# How to dynamically allocate array of pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I am currently implementing a program for file copy from one directory to another and in that program i need to allocate memory dynamically for the pointers.So is it possible to allocate memory dynamically for the `array of pointers`? if yes please guide me.
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

This dynamically allocates an array of `n` pointers to `char`:

```
char **p;
int n = 42;

p = malloc(n * sizeof *p);
```

You can then access the array like any array:

```
int i;

// Initialize all pointers to NULL
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    p[i] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Or use `calloc()` to automatically zero the allocated memory